# using wilson's theorem calculate 50!(mod 53)

Tags: number-theory

using wilson's theorem calculate

$$50!\pmod  {53}$$

I try to apply wilson's theorem  where if p is prime then $(p-1)! \equiv -1 \pmod p$

but if I take $p =51$  then $(51 -1)! \equiv -1 \pmod {51}$ but the mod here is $53$ not $51$ so how solve this kind of question

Comment: So...$52!\equiv -1 \pmod {53}$.  Therefore $50!\times 51\times 52\equiv -1 \pmod {53}$

Comment: What do you mean by $50!\pmod{53}$?

Answer (score 3):

We have in $\mathbb F_{53}$ that $$52!=50!\cdot51\cdot52=-1\iff 50!(-2)(-1)=-1\iff50!=-2^{-1}=-27=\color{red}{46} $$

Comment: I have not worked in many a field, but if he specifies $\mathbb{F}_{53}$ maybe it is ok technically? But should it not be $\mathbb{Z}_{53}$?

Comment: Technically speaking I think it si completely right to use equality signs if is clear or specified that he's doing arithmetic in $\;\Bbb F_3\;$ , and in this case $\;\Bbb F_{53}=\Bbb Z_{53}$

Comment: @nippon: dear friend, read the comments of mathreadler and Joanpemo, please. Regards.

Comment: You mean $-27=26$, not $46$, correct?

Comment: But $-27 = -27+53 = 26$